# Getting a value from a row object via DataContext in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datacontext

I have a listview that is populated from an XML file using DataTemplates. On every row a button is generated. When you click on the button I want to do something with the values on that row. So far so good.

I'm actually using the third answer from this thread [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202084603/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/7127920/wpf-listview-with-buttons-on-each-line).

The actual code (with cryptic comment) from this solution is:

```
    private void btnMoveFDAup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = ((Button)sender);
    // btn.DataContext will get you to the row object where you can retrieve the ID
}
```

When I look at btn.DataContext in the Watch Window of the Debugger I see all the wonderful data that I need:
[image: Watch window output]

The problem is: HOW DO I ACCESS THIS DATA? I need to pull in 'Name' and a couple of booleans; but I'm completely clueless.

Various attempts like

```
string name = btn.DataContext.Name;
```

Just throw compiler errors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast `btn.DataContext` to `LVData`:

```
var lvData = (LVData)btn.DataContext;
// now you can access lvData.Name, ...
```

You receive a compile error because `btn.DataContext` is of type object and doesn't know anything about `LVData` members. At runtime, it can point to any class instance (because all classes inherit from `object`). You tell the compiler that `btn.DataContext` points to a `LVData` instance by casting it.

*(More explanations here: [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). You will need this all the time.)*

Comment: Thanks. I thought a cast might be needed; but a cast to what? Thanks again!

Comment: runtime type (`LVData`) is visible in the column `Type` (in watch grid).